# $1/\det$ is a polynomial function?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Consider the algebraic group $G = \textrm{GL}_n(k)$ over an algebraically closed field $k$.  We may consider the underlying set of $G$ to be the closed set $V( Y\cdot \det(X_{ij})-1)$ in $k^{n^2+1}$.  Now, the regular functions $G \rightarrow k$ (that is, the elements of $\mathcal O_G(G)$) consist of those functions $f$ which are *regular*, that is they locally be represented by rational functions.  For example, $\frac{1}{\det(x_{ij})} \in \mathcal O_G(G)$.  However, the big result about regular functions is that when it comes to affine varieties, the ring of regular functions $\mathcal O_G(G)$ actually consists of polynomial functions $f: G \rightarrow k$.

Now, $\frac{1}{\det(x_{ij})}$ is not in the form of the polynomial.  But we know that there should exist *some* polynomial function $f = f(x_{ij},y): k^{n^2+1} \rightarrow k$ such that $f$ agrees with $\frac{1}{\det(x_{ij})}$ on $G = V( Y\cdot \det(X_{ij})-1)$.  What function could that be?  Is it obvious, or does one need to go through the proof of the result about regular functions on $\mathcal O_G(G)$ to find it?

Comment: Isn't it just $y$?

Comment: Well, $Y \det X - 1 = 0$, so the function you want is just $Y$. No?

Comment: XD of course.  I'm dumb.